# How to default checkboxes to checked while maintaining custom return value

Tags: 8, forms

I'm working on a migration project. I have a form in a custom module that creates a series of checkboxes for URLs to scrape. The form logic looks like this:

```
foreach ( \Drupal\scrape\Api\Scraper::loadUrls() as $index => $url ) {
  $form['url_' . $index] = [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => $url . ' &mdash; ' . \Drupal::l('(link)', Url::fromUri($url)),
    '#return_value' => $url,
  ];
}
```

This code does what I want it to do, but all the checkboxes default to 'unchecked'.

```
'url_0' => integer0
'url_1' => string(27) "https://myurl1.com"
'url_2' => integer0
```

I want these checkboxes to default to checked. I couldn't find documentation on how to do it in Drupal 8, so I tried several things, and finally hit upon `'#checked' => TRUE,` (or any value that evaluates truthily). Now the checkboxes are defaulting to checked.

However, even though I have `#return_value` specified, the value returned in the form submission is now `TRUE` (from kint):

```
'url_0' => boolTRUE
'url_1' => boolTRUE
'url_2' => boolTRUE
```

Since any truthy value defaults the checkbox to checked, I tried `'#value' =>  $url,` but then upon submission, the values don't indicate their checked status:

```
'url_0' => string(86) "https://myurl0.com"
'url_1' => string(27) "https://myurl1.com"
'url_2' => string(29) "https://myurl2.com"
```

I guess my final option is to have a separate, hidden value for each URL, and map checkbox values to see if the user wants that URL included.

Is there a way I can default my checkboxes to TRUE, while maintaining their `#return_value`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you can't. I just created hidden fields, and mapped them in the submit.

This is what I basically did:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $values = $form_state->getValues();

  $i = 0;

  while ( TRUE ) {
    if ( ! isset($values['checkboxes'][$i] ) {
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

That's not verbatim but basically what I did. Simple looping and checking for the checkbox value.

Comment: can you share sample?

Comment: @dresh see edited question. Not a complicated solution.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for such a late response but it is possible, I ran into this same issue using 8.5.3 the below configuration worked for me.  You just have to use both together, i successfully passed numbers, text, bool (becomes 0 or 1), and arrays through #return_value.  The class was just for formatting, you can leave that out if you're not using it.

```
'checkbox_1' => [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Checkbox 1'),
    '#default_value' => 1,         // Default to checked
    '#return_value' => "checked",  // Return the value if checked
    '#attributes' => ['class'=>['check_group']],
],
'checkbox_2' => [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => t('Checkbox 2'),
    '#default_value' => 0,         // Default to unchecked
    '#return_value' => "checked",  // Return the value if checked
    '#attributes' => ['class'=>['check_group']],
],
```

Output will look like this if you dpm($form_state->getValues()) in your submit or validate function.

```
Array
(
    [checkbox_1] => checked
    [checkbox_2] => 0
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `#default_value` property.
E.g:

```
 $form['demo'] = [
    '#type' => 'checkbox',
    '#title' => $this->t('Demo'),
    '#default_value' => TRUE,
 ];
```